# Inheritance in Class Vs Protocol

Tags: swift

I am little bit **messed up** with the following concept:

**Code 1 :**

```
class New{
    func abc(){
        print("new class")
    }
}

class ClassNew: New {
    override func abc() {
        print("derived class")
    }
}
```

**Code 2:**

```
protocol New{}

extension New{
    func abc(){
        print("new protocol")
    }
}

class ClassNew: New {
    func abc() {
        print("derived protocol")
    }
}
```

1. What is the difference between `Code 1` and `Code 2` as both of them serves the same purpose?
2. In `code 2`, `classNew` is `inheriting` from new protocol or just `conforming` to the protocol?

Any Explanation will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Class or protocols should have better naming, e.g. `MyClass` instead of `myClass`.

Comment: Changed the name, Done!

Comment: See this simple video: [Protocol-Oriented Views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AySlYrel7fc) and also read [What is Protocol Oriented Programming in Swift? What added value does it bring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530346/what-is-protocol-oriented-programming-in-swift-what-added-value-does-it-bring)

Comment: Side note : You shouldn't be able to do multiple inheritance in Swift or in Objective-C (can only have one parent class, which can have another parent class etc.). But a class can conforms to various protocols. And the purpose of Protocols or Inheritance is different.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Code 1 and code 2 are fundamentally **not the same**.

> What is the difference between Code 1 and Code 2 as both of them serves the same purpose?

No they don't. The first one defines a class hierarchy, the second defines a protocol (an API, if you like) and a type that conforms to it.

> In code 2, classNew is inheriting from new protocol or just conforming to the protocol?

It's conforming to the protocol. There's no inheritance involved (if you are being pedantic).

---

Code 1 defines a base class and a class that inherits from it. The subclass overrides the base class for the function `abc()` and it behaves as you would expect given a class hierarchy i.e.

```
let x: New = ClassNew()
let y: ClassNew = ClassNew()

print(x.abc()) // prints "derived class"
print(y.abc()) // prints "derived class"
```

Both print statements call the derived class's `abc()`

In **code 2** you define a protocol with no methods, and an extension to the protocol with an extension method. Note that this is **not** a "default method" there is nothing in the protocol to default. You then define a class that conforms to the protocol and adds a new method that happens to have the same name as the extension method. The distinction (from the pure class hierarchy) is important because the version of `abc()` called is determined statically at compile time

```
protocol New2{}

extension New2{
    func abc(){
        print("new protocol")
    }
}

class ClassNew2: New2 {
    func abc() {
        print("derived protocol")
    }
}

let y2: ClassNew2 = ClassNew2()
let x2: New2 = y2

print(x2.abc()) // prints "new protocol"
print(y2.abc()) // prints "derived protocol"
```

Even though x2 and y2 *are the same object* different versions of the function are called. This is because the compiler is not allowed to assume anything about x2 except what it can infer from the protocol. So it doesn't know that the object has an`abc()` of its own so it must call the extension function.

If you had defined the protocol like this:

```
protocol New3{
    func abc()
}

extension New3{
    func abc(){
        print("new protocol")
    }
}

class ClassNew3: New3 {
    func abc() {
        print("derived protocol")
    }
}

let y3: ClassNew3 = ClassNew3()
let x3: New3 = y3

print(x3.abc())  // prints "derived protocol"
print(y3.abc())  // prints "derived protocol"
```

This time the compiler knows that the object should have a function abc() and will only use the extension function if it doesn't. Then the normal inheritance rules for classes apply.

Answer (score 2):

**Code 2** is an example of [*protocol extensions*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521). Big difference is that you can't call `super.abc()` in **Code 2** — you have to provide a method implementation that is not in any `super` context.

Just my opinion — do not use protocol default implementation, as compiler won't save you if you forget to provide "override" when you really need one.

Comment: It is not a default implementation. The protocol declares no function to default.

Answer (score 1):

`classNew` is simply **conforming to the protocol** in the second code. This is true to every protocol in Swift as inheritance is **not currently supported** with protocols.

This also answers your first question: there is no significant difference between the two codes in *this* use case, but, generally speaking, a protocol is good for other kinds of things than subclassing.

Comment: But implementing protocols is a way of implementing multiple inheritance then how it's not true in case of single inheritance?

Comment: @ShubhamMishra protocols are nothing to do with inheritance at all.

Comment: See this link @Fogmeister : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054396/can-i-able-to-support-multiple-inheritance-with-protocol-in-swift

Comment: @ShubhamMishra I fail to see he relevance. And if you read the accepted answer it stated that protocols can be “exploited to model the idea of multiple inheritance that we are used to”. It is not inheritance in itself. It is about conformance. Not inheritance.

Comment: There is a significant difference between the two fragments. Try assigning an instance of the class to a variable of type `New` and calling `abc()`

Answer (score 1):

`Code 1` and `Code 2` are exactly same, just conceptually different.

If we put it in simple words, a `Class` defines the object itself, and a `Protocol` defines the behaviour of the object.

If compared to Java, a `protocol` is similar to `Interfaces`.

[Checkout the Protocol Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)

Comment: No they are not the same.